# New tag for controversial discussions?

Tags: discussion, tags, poo-storm

Martin has kindly suggested the use of `[poo-storm]` referenced [here.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/an-open-request-for-moderate-moderation)  I believe the first recipient of this honorary tag should be the [hackintosh thread](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-apple-beta).  All in favor?

Comment: hahahahaha well, I like to see the suggestion taken into consideration, it could be a nice indicator when a thread is going to smell bad :)

Comment: For the meta site? I think so. :-)

Comment: yes for the meta site :)

Comment: and.... done :P

Comment: There's an emoji for that! 
PILE OF POO
Unicode: U+1F4A9 (U+D83D U+DCA9), UTF-8: F0 9F 92 A9

Comment: @bmike LOL you get the credit for [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/what-tiny-thing-in-lion-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/19945#19945) and [this](http://twitter.com/grahamperrin/status/98772980351500288) and [this](http://identi.ca/notice/80281375)

Comment: @graham that's what I call winning! Thanks for the nod - I'm grinning ear to ear.

Comment: @bmike,@Graham: absolutely beautiful.  truly fantastic.  there are no words.

Comment: so how would we go about putting an icon inside the tag some tags on stackoverflow?

Comment: It's not an icon; it's just a character, right? Not all browsers will display it, but its just text. So instead of [poo-storm], use [poo-storm]

Comment: 'Doh. It's text, but SO's engine won't take random unicode in tag text. So no  tag. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Alas, it appears tag text cannot contain arbitrary unicode characters. So we are stuck with [poo-storm] as the tag and not[poo-storm] or some other cool permutation.

Perhaps John Greenleaf Whitter said it best with regard to this situation: "For all sad words of tongue and pen, The saddest are these, 'It might have been.'"